# redirect from one site to another

Tags: windows, networking, redirection, hosts-file

To avoid spending time on the internet I decidet to block several time wasting web sites I added rule redirecting several pages to localhost changine file

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

I added following line

> 127.0.0.1 joemonster.org

But great idea could be redirect it to more valuable site like [duolingo.com](https://www.duolingo.com/).
The problem is that `duolingo` is listening on port `443`.

Hosts files aren't for redirecting port but only for resolving addresses. How can I redirect joemonster to duolingo?

Comment: @and31415, yes I tried this, I've had the same results

Comment: @techie007 true, thanks for link, so I assume that local server is the best way?